# Making horizontal menu to the center of the div

Tags: html, css

I have tried to make horizontal menu and it succeed. But how to make it to the center of the div as I have tried to put `text-align:center`, `vertical-align:middle`, and `display:inline`. They are not working at all..

First of all, my HTML would be like this below

```css
.nav {
  border:1px solid #CCC;
  border-width:1px 0;
  list-style:none;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding:20px 0;
  width:100%;
  text-align: center;
}
 
ul.nav-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-family: 'latoregular';
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 100%;
    text-align:center;
}

ul.nav-menu:after {
    content: "";
    clear: both;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

ul.nav-menu li {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;
    position: relative;
}

ul.nav-menu li:first-child {
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li> <a href="#" class="selected"> HOME </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> PORTFOLIO </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> BLOG </a> </li>
        <li> <a href="#"> CONTACT </a> </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And lastly, here is [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dzxhv0Lh/).

How to push `.nav-menu` into the center of the `.nav`? Any ideas?

Comment: `.nav-menu` **is** in the center...but it's 100% wide. You could remove the width & margin and use `display:inline-block`. - http://jsfiddle.net/dzxhv0Lh/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `width` and add `display: inline-block` to your `ul.nav-menu`:

```
ul.nav-menu {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    font-family: 'latoregular';
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: inline-block; // add display: inline-block;
    text-align:center;
}
```

You've already done the rest (setting `text-align: center` on the parent container).

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dzxhv0Lh/7/)

Comment: Ahhh simple and easy wayyyyyyy! Thanks! It's great!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `width: 100%` and add `display: inline-block;` from and to `.nav-menu`.

That way the width of  the element will be determined by the child elements, and the `margin: 0 auto;` will push the menu to the middle of its parent.

Answer (score -1):

add a value to the width of nav-menu

```
 ul.nav-menu {
        list-style: none;
        padding: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        line-height: 14px;
        font-family: 'latoregular';
        margin: 0 auto;
        width: 300px;
        text-align:center;
    }


http://jsfiddle.net/dzxhv0Lh/1/
```

Comment: But the context of the question wasn't specific about dynamic nature of the page. My response was based on a common mistake being made by people when trying to align Divs and other elements to the centre without specifying the width of the element.