# Menu to the center of the header

Tags: html, css

I am setting up a new menu for a HTML website... Issue is that I am not able to center of the DIV and now it is at the left side. https://antontechnologies.com/

I tried [Making horizontal menu to the center of the div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27404004/making-horizontal-menu-to-the-center-of-the-div) and this did not help

```
.flat-mega-menu {
    margin: 0 auto;         /* margin for align container center */
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 999;
    font-size: 1em;
    display: block;
    /*max-width: 1280px; */     /* container max-width 1280px */
    min-height: 60px;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: "nunito regular";
    min-width: 180px;
}
```

Menu should be center of the page instead left..

Comment: Hi there. Please [edit] your question to include the relevant code directly into your question instead of linking to an external site. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) property:

```
ul.collapse {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out
[image]

As you can see , I jsut added `text-align:center` to your `ul` and thats it :)

Comment: Hi.. thank you... but is does not change for me some reason, http://prntscr.com/mm0jse